# .ipa from phonegap(html 5 app) wont install on iphone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I have made an app for iphone, using phonegap and html 5.
Now, i can download from build.phonegap.com a .ipa file(instalation file for iphone).
I have searched google on how to install it, and its simply drag and drop in itunes.
So, i did that, and there is an app icon in itunes.
When i click on "install", it will install.
The only problem is, it wont change its status.
So after 20 minutes it will still say "installing".
Does the iphone need to be jailbroken, cause it isnt.
So, how can i install the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sync the device after pressing install. There is a sync button on the same screen press that and check..